# Notify to refresh ember.js application after successful deployment on GitLab CI/CD

Tags: ember.js, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

We are using the awesome **Gitlab CI/CD workflow** and had been satisfied with the process. A lot of **Merge Requests** could happen everyday and we want to make sure that our application is updated on realtime whenever our pipeline jobs is successful.

For instance our master branch could also be deployed on staging whenever Merge Request is accepted. Here is our example `deploy_staging` job on `gitlab-ci.yml`.

```
deploy_staging:
  type: deploy
  script:
    - yarn install
    - node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember deploy staging --activate
  environment:
    name: staging
  only:
    - master
```

Since ember is a **Single Page Application** and once new deployment is shipped and available, ember couldn't recognized the new changes. Hence we need to refresh the page to be updated.

The other downside to this idea is, we can't afford to refresh the page if end user is in the middle of transaction. So my thought is to make a notification to refresh the page similar to any mobile app when updates are available they just go to the link and click the update manually.

Now this problem is narrowed down to this:

How can we sent signal to the running ember application so we can prompt a notification to refresh the page whenever updates are available *(after successful CI/CD delivery)*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you'll want service workers :)
[Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) are usually how most other sites notify about updates.

For ember, setting them up is fairly simple, we have [ember-service-worker](http://ember-service-worker.com/) to get your caching and manifest going, and then we have [ember-service-worke-update-notify](https://github.com/topaxi/ember-service-worker-update-notify) for automatic notification of asset updates.

Though, there is a PR here: https://github.com/topaxi/ember-service-worker-update-notify/pull/3 to notify about updates in a more automated way -- the current way only notifies about an update upon refresh and load of cached assets.

I recently opened this PR, because I think with `@pollingInterval={{5000}}`, that would be the ideal interval to check for update, where every 5 seconds, we see if there is an update.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Roel feel free to upvote / click the checkmark if this works out for you :)
(the points encourage me to keep helping people out)
((...I don't find self-worth in internet points...))

Comment: sure! after i test the ember-service-worker im in the middle of understanding it now :) thanks for pointing